# How to persist Chrome Developer Tools Deactivate Breakpoints state after reloading page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How to persist Chrome Developer Tools Deactivate Breakpoints state after reloading page ?

Many moons ago, the state is remembered correctly after reloading page,

e.g.
if breakpoints are deactivated, it will stay as deactivated after reloading page.

However current version of Chrome v60.xx (maybe v56 and above?) re-enable breakpoints after reloading page. Any workaround ?

[image: deactivate breakpoints]

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Care to report on https://crbug.com if it wasn't reported already?

Comment: Probably related: https://crbug.com/459499

Comment: reported https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=751040